# Disk usage spikes to 100% & Transfer speeds drop to 0 then computer locks up whenever doing a file transfer

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8, file-transfer, task-manager

I've done a bit of searching but haven't been able to figure out what I can do that works. My HDD seems to be on the fritz so I am trying to backup my emails (2GB) to an external drive so I can swap the drive to a SSD. Whenever I attempt to transfer the files the disk usage shoots to 100% after it is about 5% into the transfer. I tried to zip up the file while breaking it down into smaller files (100mb/each) thinking maybe the size is too much for my goofy drive but the disk spikes during this as well and will not complete.

---

A bit of background:

All started last week, programs started to hang and everything just seemed much slower. The day after having this issue the disk usage would spike to 100% forcing me to restart the pc to fix. After logging back in and 20 min or so passed it would happen again. I managed to update all drivers, cleanup, optimize files and run a malware scan with System Mechanic as well as disabling any non essential startup services. After doing all of this I was good for about an hour and a half but the problem came back. The computer was shut down for the weekend and Monday the PC would no longer turn on, it was saying to choose a bootable drive.

I was able to run through the Windows troubleshoot utility to do a refresh on the PC. Now luckily I'm able to log back in and the disk doesn't spike to 100% on its own but it does when I try to transfer my emails to the external drive which is the dilemma i find myself in now.

I apologize for the novel but thought it might be helpful to know the events leading up to now. Any idea of what I could do would be greatly appreciated!

Note:
The PC is running Windows 8.1 and about 4-5 years old. Nothing new installed or changed in any way that I'm aware of. Machine was running perfectly fine up until last week.

Comment: Why is it a bad thing that the disk usage goes to 100%?

Comment: Well whenever it goes to 100% my entire computer locks up and I have to restart. I've left it for over an hour and still shows 100% on disk. I just figured that was the issue, i'll clarify my question

Comment: The 100% disk utilization isn't bad if it is actually copying (though I think windows rarely shows 100% for a normal transfer operation). However, if it is locking your computer, then what sounds like is happening is you begin your backup or zip and then encounter a bad sector on your disk. The computer then goes nuts repeatedly trying to re-read that sector. Depending on the error handling capability of the code doing the backup or zip -- that could well lock your computer. Open an administrator prompt and run `sfc /scannow` to confirm.

Comment: Check your disc's SMART data, which will verify whether it is failing or not. Standard copying will spend a long time retrying bad sectors, when disc use is apparently constant, and depending on the size of the bad area it could be in this state for quite some time, though you should be able to see the target file growing or changing, however slowly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

STOP USING THE SYSTEM NOW. You are making it worse.

What you have described is typical of a failing hard drive. The more you use it the harder recovery is. If your non backed up data is worth $$$ get your disk to a recovery specialist, otherwise read on for DIY solution.

You need to get another drive which is at least as large as the failing drive and do a bit copy if the drive/data partition USING AN APPROPRIATE DATA RECOVERY TOOL.  I'd suggest gnu ddrescue (but its Linux based). These tools will try and pull as much data off the drive as they can in such a way as to get easily readable data and then focus on damaged blocks. You can also restart the copy where it left off, and see progress and failure spots. I typically do at least 2 passes - a forward pass until the disk starts erroring, then stop it and do a backward pass for as long as I can wait/until all data is recoverred. (Process can 99.9% complete in hours, the rest might take months for virtually no data while making additional from-scratch recovery attempts less likely to succeed)

Once you have your bit copy, you can move the important emails and files without the system locking up.

Comment: Thank you, I have already stopped using the system out of fear of making things worse. I figured it was the drive starting to fail and just needed a way to back up my emails somehow. Loosing my emails would be a huge inconvenience but not catastrophic so I will try your DIY solution.

Thank you so much for the info